# Products of primes of the form $an + b$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

What is the asymptotic order of numbers divisible by no primes except those of the form $an+b$ ($a$, $b$ fixed)?

Surely (except for the trivial cases) they are of order strictly between that of he primes and of all numbers.

Comment: I would guess something like $n/\sqrt{\log n}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: That would be my guess as well. Is this in Hardy & Wright, perhaps?

Comment: Don't own it, alas, and don't remember seeing the result there. However, the above is what one gets for sums of two squares, and the numbers expressible as a sum of two squares are a constant multiple away from numbers divisible only by $2$ or primes of the form $4k+1$. My guess is that a partial imitation of the proof of the two squares result would do the job.

Comment: Given a subset of the primes $\mathcal{S}$ with positive density $\alpha$, I believe the asymptotics for the counting function for the integers formed by products of those primes will be $$\sim C \frac{x}{(\log x)^{1-\alpha}},$$ for some constant $C$.  The idea is that the function $$\zeta_\mathcal{S}(s)=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{S}} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$$ will have a singularity of the form $\frac{1}{(s-1)^{\alpha}}$ and then integrating $ \frac{x^s}{(s-1)^{\alpha}}dx$ gives a main term of $$\frac{x}{(\log x)^{1-\alpha}}.$$